# How to model messages in Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework

I am building an application with the Phoenix Framework v1.1.0 and Postgres v9.4 that contains messaging functionality.  I am not referring to instant messaging, but mail type of messages where a user can create a message and address it to 1 or more other users, which in turn can reply.  I am not very good with SQL databases and am more used to MongoDB with Meteor.  What is the most efficient way to model this type of table in Postgres so that the message can be delivered to 1 or more users and responded to?  I was originally thinking of creating an array of the recipients, but I am stuck there and I'm sure there is a better way.  My schema looks as such:

```
create table(:messages) do
  add :from, :string
  add :subject, :string
  add :body, :text
  add :to, :array, :string
  timestamps
```

So, my questions are these:

1. What model should I use to represent messages in Postgres?
2. How do I search the messages in the db so that the users are immediately informed of the message in their inbox, and respond?
3. Would using sockets (channels in Phoenix) make the job any easier as it does for chat-type of functionality?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `phoenix-framework`, so my answer treats about 1 and 2 from your list of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Design

Schema for messages handling could involve a `many-to-many` relationship between `app_users` and `messages`. This would make use of the relational characteristic of Postgres database.

In table `users_messages` there will be at least one row for the recipient of the message. You may add roles like DW, UDW etc in another dictionary table and put the information about the recipient type inside this table.

```
CREATE TABLE app_users ( -- one user is represented as one row here
 id serial primary key,
 ...
);

CREATE TABLE messages ( -- one message is represented as one row here
 id bigserial primary key,
 id_sender int references app_users(id),
 send_date timestamp default clock_timestamp(),
 notify_date timestamp default null,
 ...
);

CREATE TABLE users_messages ( -- one message is represented as 1..* rows here
 id bigserial primary key, -- I prefer to use sequences in every table, that's up to you
 id_recipient int references app_users(id),
 id_message bigint references messages(id),
 is_read boolean,
 ...
);
```

### New / unread messages queries

I've chosen `DISTINCT` as you only wanted to notify particular users about new message(s) in their inbox, not what messages are they.

Query to get recipients that should be informed about unread messages in their inbox would be as simple as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_recipient
FROM users_messages
WHERE is_read is FALSE
```

If you need to notify users about the change state from last fetching you could for example get this from `messages` table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT um.id_recipient
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN users_messages um
WHERE m.notify_date is NULL
      AND um.is_read is FALSE
```

and update column `messages.notify_date` for all fetched `messages.id`, which could be done in SQL, or in your framework. That would require another query, which is left as an exercise to the reader.

However, if you only care about a particular user being notified about new messages, without reminding him that he has some unread messages (*which is actually how e-mail notification works*) then you could get those by running:

```
SELECT DISTINCT um.id_recipient
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN users_messages um
WHERE m.notify_date is NULL
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for.  But what would the insert statement look like with multiple tables being involved?

Comment: You can't insert rows into different tables in one statement. This should either be on the application part, or using plain `SQL`. You could use `WITH` clause combined with `RETURNING` and then execute second `INSERT` statement in one query for a particular message. Read a bit here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html . I'd suggest to work this out on the application if it's possible.

Comment: I really don't know much about SQL and Postgres, but originally chose it because the functionality comes built-in with Phoenix.  There is an Elixir client for RethinkDB and I could use that if I wanted to.  Do you have any experience with Rethink or NoSQL in general?  Could I better represent, store, query, and update messages using this type of database?

Comment: This is a question for Google. There are many articles that cover this topic. I believe that it's ok for your case to store it in Postgres.

Answer (score -1):

First, Sorry I'm not very familier with `phoenix`, so I do my best to answer your questions generally.

1. You can use ARRAY type in postgresql:

this way:

```
CREATE TABLE message (
    from_user            text,
    to_users             text[],
    cc_users             text[],
    body                 text
    ...
);
```

2. you can run a query like:

   `SELECT * FROM message WHERE '$uid' = ANY (to);`

Comment: I'm afraid `to` and `from` are reserved words in Postgres. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: @ConsiderMe Thanks for hint